# change layouts on rotation without triggering the onCreate method

Tags: android, rotation

I have made two layouts with the same name and placed one in the layout-land folder so that it renders when the device is in landscape mode. This works but the layouts don't look exactly alike. And in the view I'm using a `ViewFlipper` so the there are two views in each of them. Once I rotate the view, it goes to the `onCreate` event and runs the activity so that the first view in the `ViewFlipper` is shown. I want it to flip to the other view if it rotates and I want it to flip to the correct view of the two (landscape or portrait).

I've put this in the above activity class:

```
 Activity(ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation | Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.ScreenSize)
```

So now it wont trigger the `onCreate` event but it doesn't load the right view. If I am in landscape and rotate it, it just rotates the view and doesn't use the portrait view.

Comment: `ConfigurationChanges = Android.Content.PM.ConfigChanges.Orientation ` do not use this unless you **really** understand what it does.  It will not solve your problem, it will simply cover over bugs in your handling of the life cycle methods.  Post your onCreate() code.

Answer (score 1):

You have to **save** and **load** the **last state** instead of preventing the screen rotation.

please see the following topics

[Save state of activity when orientation changes android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022677/save-state-of-activity-when-orientation-changes-android)

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/recreating.html

[Restoring state of TextView after screen rotation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5179686/restoring-state-of-textview-after-screen-rotation)

[Saving Activity state in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151777/saving-activity-state-in-android)

or google it for more info.

Comment: It sounds like it should be the solution but if i use the code:   protected override void OnSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
            {
                    OnSaveInstanceState(outState);
                    outState.PutInt("Position", position);
            } it will break without giving me any breakinginfo. This is all i got: The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).