# Keeping data when screen orientation change

Tags: java, android, layout, landscape, portrait

So I'm coding an Android app with Visual Studio. I want a certain Activity with both orientation portrait and landscape. When I turned my device, the data in my Activity disappeared. So I checked on internet and found a line to put in the manifest which keep the data and this worked !
android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
except that all of my views were in disorder and deplaced.I'm using two different layout. one for the protrait view and the other for the landscape. I want to keep the data end switch the layout, any ideas ?
thanx

Comment: learn about Activity Lifecycle. For your needs, onSaveInstantState is important....https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: Don't use `configChanges` it's a very bad way to handle orientation change.  Basically you have to use an id on every so its state can be saved automaically. If you have data in variables, you can save them in `onSaveInstanteState` put putting them to the bundle and recover them in `onCreate` when Activity is restarted. Fragments can keep state with `setRetainInstante(true)` You can read more about that: [Android Developpers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html), [Codepath](https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Handling-Configuration-Changes)

Comment: Woah!! I got down voted so fast :O. Ok use this library it's easy 
https://github.com/frankiesardo/icepick

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android: alternate layout xml for landscape mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4858026/android-alternate-layout-xml-for-landscape-mode)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Save state of activity when orientation changes android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13022677/save-state-of-activity-when-orientation-changes-android)

Answer (score 1):

override

```
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)
```

method and save value in outState variable in key value pair

in

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

when orientation will chage savedInstanceState variable will have same value which you save in

```
onSaveInstanceState
```

Note: when activity will launch first time

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
```

savedInstanceState will have null value

Answer (score -2):

Just put this line with activity tag of your Mainfest.xml file

`android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"`

Final code will be look like:

`<activity android:name="com.xyz.myapp.MainActivity" android:label="@string/app_name"
android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|screenLayout|screenSize|orientation"/>`

Comment: It didn't work. It keep the data but I also want to change the view

Comment: write xml in each folder with same name `layout/main.xml` for portrait and `layout-land/main.xml` for landscape for more [info visit this](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html)

Comment: I did it but it won't change. I think the line i put in the manifest juste keep the data and don't handle the switch of layout