# Custom image view looses state on Marshmallow

Tags: android, imageview, orientation-changes, onsaveinstancestate, onrestoreinstancestate

I am using the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library in my Android project. The project contains the [SaveStatePhotoView](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/PhotoViewTest/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/example/testphotoview/SaveStatePhotoView.java) which is used to keep the state (zoom level, position) of the image view on configuration changes (rotation, ...).

```
// SaveStatePhotoView.java

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }

    final SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(
        new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {

        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            restoreSavedState(ss);
            getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
        }
    });
}
```

The view works as desired on Android 7.1.1 and Android 9.
On **Android 6.0.1** the **state is lost**: the image view resets to its initial state when the device is rotated.

I prepared a [simple project](https://github.com/johnjohndoe/PhotoViewTest) to demonstrate the issue. Please note that I am using [PhotoView 1.3.1](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView/releases/tag/1.3.1) on purpose because I cannot include transitive `androidx` dependencies at the moment.

Comment: I've found this answer which explains well how to handle the instance state loss on device rotation: https://stackoverflow.com/a/13023121/7507788, I think you could try to handle the restore of the imageview in the onCreate as it shows in the answer above, let me know if it helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**N.B** This does not seem to be an issue with **PhotoView** version 2.3.0.

**PhotoView** undergoes two layouts when recreated for API 23 and under. For API 24+, there is only one layout pass. What happens when there are two passes is that the scale (a matrix) that is restored in `onRestoreInstanceState()` of `SaveStatePhotoView` is reset. In your code, you are removing the global layout listener after the first pass so, when the matrix is reset on the second layout pass, you are not catching it. For API 24+, there is only one pass and the scale is restored and not reset. This is why you see an issue for API 23 and not for 24.

I think that the real fix is in **PhotoView**. A vanilla `ImageView` also undergoes two layout passes, so I don't think the extra layout pass is something that **PhotoView** causes. I do think, however, that **PhotoView** mishandles the scaling matrix for certain APIs.

You can address this issue by setting the scale on the second pass for API 24+ by doing something like this:

```
@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Parcelable state) {
    if (!(state instanceof SavedState)) {
        super.onRestoreInstanceState(state);
        return;
    }

    final SavedState ss = (SavedState) state;
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(ss.getSuperState());

    getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        private int invocationCount = 0;

        // Only one layout pass for M and up. Otherwise, we'll see two and the
        // scale set in the first pass is reset during the second pass, so the scale we
        // set doesn't stick until the 2nd pass.
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            setScale(Math.min(ss.scale, getMaximumScale()), getWidth() * ss.pivotX,
                    getHeight() * ss.pivotY, false);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.M || ++invocationCount > 1) {
                getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The preceding is based upon the supplied demo app running **PhotoView** version 1.3.1.

Comment: Great analysis! Thank you. - Where exactly did you see that `PhotoView` undergoes  two layout passes on Marshmallow?

Comment: @JJD Just override `onLayout()` in your custom view, rotate the device and count how many time it's called. For API 24+ it is just once and for lower APIs it is called twice. I did a quick test and it is the same for a straight `ImageView`.

Comment: Thank you once again. The workaround seems to be successful. Merci.