# Disappearing texts in textviews/edittexts

Tags: android

I have problem with all texts in textviews/edittexts. App goes to background, I use few other apps on phone than I go back to my app and all texts (on every activities) disappear. All texts are set up in layouts xml files from string.xml.
I haven't got any error for that in log cat. What can be wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post some code? I.e. activity.start()/create()/stop()/finish(), layout, resources, ...

Comment: try change color of text other than black or white

Comment: write some code from your activity and manifest file as well.

Comment: add code to save the text in onPause() and then display it in Onresume().  check the lifcycle of application http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html  . Provide your code !

Answer (score 0):

from Activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.information);

    String versionName = null;

    try {
        versionName = getPackageManager().getPackageInfo(getPackageName(), 0).versionName;
    } catch (NameNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(versionName != null) {
        ResizableTextView versionNumberView = (ResizableTextView) findViewById(R.id.information_version_number);
        versionNumberView.setText(version);
    }
}
```

in manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name="pl.sf.mobile.activities.InformationActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait" >
</activity>
```

layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/bg1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="90" >

        <include
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            layout="@layout/title_bar" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/information_version"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="10"
            android:background="@color/gray_light"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:weightSum="100" >

            <pl.sf.mobile.components.ResizableTextView
                android:id="@+id/information_version"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="75"
                android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:text="@string/version"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

            <pl.sf.mobile.components.ResizableTextView
                android:id="@+id/information_version_number"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="15"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:textColor="@color/black"
                android:textSize="23px"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:visibility="visible" />
        </LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```

ResizableTextView

```
public class ResizableTextView extends TextView {

    private float sizeF = 0;

    public ResizableTextView(Context context) {
        super(context);
        resizeTextFont();
    }

    public ResizableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        resizeTextFont();
    }

    public ResizableTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
        resizeTextFont();
    }

    private void resizeTextFont() {

        if (sizeF == 0)
            sizeF = getTextSize();

        float newSize = sizeF * Params.SCALED_WIDTH;
        setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, newSize);
        invalidate();
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Share the code you are using plz. The description is very brief. BTW, you can have a look at this link [how to save state with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState while orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259776/how-to-save-state-with-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-while-orie)