# Frequent Orientation Change is giving Null Pointer Exception for Textview

Tags: android, textview

My Problem is, TextView is giving **java.lang.NullPointerException** if I **do Orientation changes** frequently. I pasted my code below. Am I missing something?

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    if (title.getText().toString() != null) {      //Getting Null Exception here
        Log.i("onSaveInstanceState", "  "+title.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("title", title.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

--

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.add, null);
    title =(TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title);

    if (savedInstanceState.getString("title") != null) {
        Log.i("on create", " "+savedInstanceState.getString("title"));
        title.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("title"));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {

    if (title.getText() != null) {      //Getting Null Exception here
        Log.i("onSaveInstanceState", "  "+title.getText().toString());
        outState.putString("title", title.getText().toString());
    }
}
```

You're comparing the result of evaluating something that's null, that way it will give you a NullPointerException.

**UPDATE**

Reffer to this SO Post where the accepted answer points out that you need to search again for the TextView widget in onSaveInstanceState method.

> [how to save state with onSaveInstanceState and onRestoreInstanceState while orientation change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10259776/how-to-save-state-with-onsaveinstancestate-and-onrestoreinstancestate-while-orie)

Comment: thanks for ur reply,"title.getText()" itself giving null pointer exception,Any Idea?

Comment: Have you declared 'title' outside of you onCreate() method?